# MKOverlayRenderer cut and blur with zooming iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm struggling with a issue related to **MapKit**.

I create a list of **MKPolygon** based on my geofence's data from the server.

```
+ (MKPolygon *)polygonFromPoints:(NSArray *)points interiorPolygons:(NSArray *)polygons{

     NSInteger numberOfCoordinates = [points count];
     CLLocationCoordinate2D *polygonPoints = malloc(numberOfCoordinates * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

     NSInteger index = 0;
     for (NSArray *pointArray in points) {
          polygonPoints[index] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([pointArray[1] floatValue], [pointArray[0] floatValue]);
          index++;
     }

     MKPolygon *polygon;
     if (polygons) {
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygonPoints count:numberOfCoordinates interiorPolygons:polygons];
     } else {
        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:polygonPoints count:numberOfCoordinates];
     }

     free(polygonPoints);
     return polygon;  }
```

And add it to the map as MKOverlayRender

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

    if([overlay isKindOfClass: [MKCircle class]]){
        MKCircleRenderer *circleRender = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:(MKCircle *)overlay];
        circleRender.fillColor = [ [Common colorWithHexString:BlueGeoFence] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];

        return circleRender;
    }else if([overlay isKindOfClass: [MKPolygon class]]){

        MKPolygonRenderer *polygonRenderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon *)overlay];
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = [ [Common colorWithHexString:BlueGeoFence] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];

        return polygonRenderer;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

However, when i zoom in or change the map's position the overlays are **cut** and have some kind of **blur effect**.

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The source of the problem was that MKPolygon was being created with interior polygons that were not actually interior polygons. Check your data and ensure that your interior polygon coordinates are actually within the bounds of your larger polygon.